# Column not found error in Criteria

Tags: mysql, symfony1, criteria, propel

I'm working on a symfony project and i need to query a many to many relationship, so i made this criteria based function to query the database:

```
    //Create Criteria Object
    $c1 = new Criteria();
    //Selecting the rows in the link table that matches the Table1 id (parameter)
    $c1->add(LinktablePeer::TBL1_CODIGO,$parameter,Criteria::EQUAL);
    //Selecting the rows in Table2 that matched with the last query
    $c1->addJoin(LinktablePeer::TBL2_CODIGO,Table2Peer::TBL2_CODIGO);
    $list = LinktablePeer::doSelect($c1);
```

but it throws me this strange error

> [wrapped: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'link_table.ID' in 'field list']

Is strange because i have no column named ID in that table. Why is this happening? How can i fix it?

### The question in other words:

Is there an option for the `php symfony propel:build-model` command that prevents generating the "ID" column for those tables that don't have a primary key?
Thank you for your time ;)

Comment: I know is not the solution, but testing the code, i've discovered that in BaseLinkTablePeer class there is an atribute called ID, and commenting all the references to this attribute the error does not appear. May this be an auto-generated attribute suposed to be a primary key?

Comment: Do you have a primary key in your table? I mean the field, which unique identify the record (attribute: `primaryKey: true`).

Comment: no, its a link table, so its primary key is a composition of the linked table's primary keys. How can i specify that?

Comment: Try to add 2 primary key attributes to this 2 fields: `tbl_codigo: { type: integer, required: true, primaryKey: true, foreignClass: Table1, foreignReference: id, onDelete: CASCADE }` `tb2_codigo: { type: integer, required: true, primaryKey: true, foreignClass: Table2, foreignReference: id, onDelete: CASCADE }`

Comment: This would be the solution if i created the model directly from schema.yml. The problem is that i generated the schema from an existing SQL database and in this model there are a lot of link tables like this causing the error, so modify manually all link tables in schema is not a solution. I'm asking for a configuration option of the `propel:build-model` command that prevents generate the primary keys if not defined in the schema.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the problem was **the dump command task was trying to export a view in my mysql database**.
When I specifically defined the tables I wanted to export using `-classes="..."`, the error went away.

For example:

```
symfony propel:data-dump --classes="{table},{tablew},..."  fixtures.yml
```